# This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.2

Tags: react-native

After create new project with react native cli, I opened android project on android studio.
I am getting this error(build field).

`This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.2`

[image]

As you can see on attached image, I am using version 4.2.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same error when I worked with the old version of android studio.
When I upgraded the android studio version to the latest version, the error was disappeared.
I hope it can be helpful for you.
Thank you.